# Set the Facebook preview picture when sharing with AddThis

Tags: html, facebook, addthis

Is there a way to set the preview picture of the Facebook sharing when you insert the AddThis widget in a HTML page?

If it isn't possible, is there something that I can do in the HTML page that can "suggest" the right preview picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the AddThis widget can't set the image that is used in the preview by Facebook.  Facebook scrapes the page and looks for og:image tag on the page you're trying to share.  So if you want to "suggest" which image Facebook should use, just specify the following:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="[LINK_TO_IMAGE]"/>
```

You can read more about how to use other meta tags with Facebook here:

http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

Good luck

Comment: A litle tip: checkout og:url also, if it's wrong it may cause issues and  og:image won't work.